# get the key value pair where the value contains a string in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python:

```
dict_example  = {'a': ['ab', 1, 2], 'b': ['sa', 23, 43], 'c': ['qw', 2, 12]}
```

How can I get the key value pair where the value contains the string 'sa'? I did this:

```
sub_str = 'qw'
{k: v for k, v in dict_example if v == sub_str}
```

Comment: `if sub_str in v` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
sub_str = 'qw'
{k: v for k, v in dict_example.items() if sub_str in v}
```

You want to see if the string is contained in the value, not if the string equals the value (which is a list)

Comment: As a note: Py2.7 you need to do `dct.items()`

Comment: Yes I do! Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Yep! I tested it out in both and it worked. Try it yourself too!